# print rest of line after match with grep

Tags: grep

ok, this is driving me crazy!
I am trying to grep some info from a log file and add it to a summary in a email notification.

from log:

> 2019/07/22 11:36:03 [14396] Number of created files: 3 (reg: 2, dir:
>   1)

Now I want the print to be only the numbers at the end, 3, 2, 1 or maybe the entire last part 3 (reg: 2, dir: 1)

I have tried different things and this is the closest I got, but it only prints the number 3 and not the rest of the info I want.

```
nf=$(grep -o 'created files:' $logfile) | cut -d\   -f3)
```

Is this possible at all?

Edit:

Ok, so I got it working using `nf=$(grep -Po 'created files: \K.*' "$logfile")`

In my summary I add $nf to get the output like this `Created $nf new files` giving me this result

> Created 3 (reg: 2, dir: 1) new files

Now, can I somehow split it up even more so my result will be something like this?
Created 1 directory and 2 files

Maybe using two separate grep commands to output the different variables, one for dir and one for reg on that line?

Comment: That last command should have `grep -o 'created files:.*'` or `grep 'created files:'` since `grep -o` with a constant string pattern would only print that string.

Answer (score 4):

If your `grep` supports perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE):

```
$ grep -Po 'created files: \K.*' "$logfile"
3 (reg: 2, dir: 1)
```

To save the numbers into a `bash` array:

```
$ numbers=( $(grep -o 'created files:.*' "$logfile" | grep -o '[0-9]\+') )
$ echo ${numbers[@]}
3 2 1
$ echo "${numbers[0]}, ${numbers[1]}, ${numbers[2]}"
3, 2, 1
```

Comment: The first part worked. Can you please explain what the different part in that command does?

Comment: With the `-P` option you can use `\K` to match the whole pattern, but `created files: ` is not included in the output. Only everything after that is in the output (`.*`).

Comment: What's the output of the second example? Are you using a different shell?

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
$ perl -ne 'print "$1 $2 $3\n" if /created files: (\d+) \(reg: (\d+), dir: (\d+)\)/' < "$logfile"
3 2 1
```

or with `sed`:

```
$ sed -nEe 's/.*created files: ([0-9]+) \(reg: ([0-9]+), dir: ([0-9]+)\)/\1 \2 \3/p' "$logfile"
3 2 1
```

Both do mainly the same thing: match the whole ending part of the line (not just `created files`), but capture (with `(...)`) the numbers and print them or replace the line with them.

Answer (score 0):

Using `cut` to extract all fields after 3:

```
grep -o 'created files:' $logfile | cut -d" " -f3-
```

Comment: I tried this but it dont give any output at all

Answer (score 0):

To fix your command:

- Add `.*` to the pattern to include the rest of the line in your `grep` output.
- Use `-f3-` to select all fields from 3rd to the end.

-->

```
grep -o 'created files: .*' "$logfile" | cut -d\  -f3-
```

Comment: ok, so f3 prints only field3, while -f3- prints field 3 and to the end of the line?

Comment: exactly! you can use e.g. `-f3-6` to select fields 3 to 6, but if you omit the `6`, it just selects all fields til the end.